# How to notify change in ItemSource for repeater view Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to implement ItemSource in StackLayout in Xamarin..Fforms using RepeaterView. [Example here](http://www.qimata.com/?p=7671).

Now whenever there is a change in ObservableCollection in ViewModel, RepeaterView Class is not able to notify the change as there is no **INotifyCollectionChanged** property. How to add that property to the **RepeaterView class**?

Here's my code:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _userName = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> UserName
{
    get
    {
        return _userName;
    } 
    set 
    { 
        SetProperty(ref _userName, value); 
    } 
}
```

On button click I'm adding strings to the List:

```
UserName.Add("User_1");
UserName.Add("User_2"); 
UserName.Add("User_3"); 
UserName.Add("User_4");
```

Comment: Do you want to know when `public IEnumerable ItemsSource` collection changed? Like when new item added/removed?

Comment: @Egor Gromadskiy Yes.I'm using the same example which is given in the link. But when I change the list the Ui is not getting updated and the newly added element is not reflecting on the UI.

Comment: Is `PageLinks` `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Yes its an ObservableCollection<string> of type string.

Comment: Could you post code, how are you adding new items?

Comment: **ViewModel**   
  private ObservableCollection<string> _userName = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> UserName
        {
            get { return _userName; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _userName, value); }
        }


on button click I'm adding strings to the List :
                UserName.Add("User_1");
                UserName.Add("User_2");
                UserName.Add("User_3");
                UserName.Add("User_4");

Comment: Why not use the ListView? What extra does a repeater bring? Observable collection will notify of changed when something is added or removed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

`var names = new List<string>();
names.Add("User1");
names.Add("User2");
names.Add("User3");
UserName = new ObservableCollection(names);`